# How can I use Basic authentication or JWT to the same route in Node?

Tags: node.js, jwt, basic-authentication, koa

Is there any way to use Basic Authentication or JWT to the same route in Node, using Koajs?

I tried 2 approachs:

1. Using Koa middleware,  call `next()` when it have had a Bearer token or when have had a Basic authentication, create a token and set to ctx.headers, but it didn't work
2. Using getToken from koa-jwt, but I can't return a promise to load user information in order to create a token.

Comment: are you trying to switch your auth strategy between jwt or basic auth at run time in a single route? is that your question?

Comment: Yes, depending on Authorization header.

Comment: Can you show some sample code of what you have done? i would create a checkAuth route middleware and test if the token is a valid jwt or a valid base64 string and then act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I forgot to use `await` when call `next()`

Thx @shanks for your time!

Here is the working code:

**route.js**

```
'use strict'

import Koa from 'koa'
import mount from 'koa-mount'
import jwt from 'koa-jwt'
import basicAuth from './basic-auth'
import HomeRouter from './home/router'
import projectRouter from './v1/project/router'

export default new Koa().
  use(mount('/', HomeRouter.routes())).
  use(basicAuth).
  use(jwt({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET })).
  use(mount('/v1/projects', projectRouter.routes()))
```

**basic-auth.js**

```
'use strict'

import { chain } from 'lodash'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import User from 'app/v1/user/model'

function _createAccessToken(user) {

  return jwt.sign({
    id: user.id,
    email: user.email
  }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
}

export default async function basicAuth(ctx, next) {

  const header = ctx.headers.authorization
  if (/basic/i.test(header)) {

    const password = chain(header).
      split(' ').
      last().
      value()

    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        apiPassword: Buffer.from(password, 'base64').toString()
      }
    })

    if (!user) return ctx.throw(401)
    const token = _createAccessToken(user)
    ctx.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
  }
  await next()
}
```